# Handling Login Authorization with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, postman

Here I'm carrying out the GET method to list the data by authenticating the login credentials, but when I pass the token in value in the header it directly `catch` the error message. is anything I'm doing wrong?

**Authentication Middleware - authentication.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
const access_token = req.headers["authorization"];

 if (!access_token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied! no token provided.");

 try {
   const decoded = jwt.verify(access_token, "SECRET_JWT_CODE");
   req.receive = decoded;
   next();
 } catch (error) {
   res.status(400).send("invalid token.");
 }
};

module.exports = authenticate;
```

[image: postman]

console.log(req.headers)
[image: console.log]

**GET method**

```
const authenticate = require("./authentication.js");

router.get("/admin", authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const receive = await SomeModel.find();
    res.json(receive);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

**login**

```
router.post("/admin/sign_in", (req, res) => {
   if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
     res.json({ error: "email and password is required" });
     return;
   }
   login
     .findOne({ email: req.body.email })
     .then((admin) => {
       if (!admin) {
         res.json({ err: "user does not exist" });
       } else {
     if (!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, admin.password)){
      res.json({ err: "password does not match" });
        } else {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              id: admin._id,
              email: admin.email,
            },
            SECRET_JWT_CODE
          );
           res.json({
             responseMessage: "Everything worked as expected",
             access_token: token,
           });
         }
       }
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       err.message;
    });
 });
```

Comment: do a print req.headers["authorization"] to figure out your problem further

Comment: Try logging the error in console and post it here

Comment: print(req.headers)

Comment: I have printed the req.header but I can't figure out the problem. you can find the post above.

Comment: Do you use the same private key "SECRET_JWT_CODE" when creating token?
Also can you add the code where you use this auth middleware?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes I have used same `SECRET_JWT_CODE` while creating a token. I have added the code above.

Comment: And also can you add the come where you generate the token?

Comment: Can you `console.log(token)` in the login route and add the token as string to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah  here it is -
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzNTAzOTI0MTE3MmJlOWQxZTljYWY3YiIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY2MjAzOTExfQ.nNcxzrNZI_xNQTOm-EmHvgl5eTJn5xq5G2woLQQfjd4`

Comment: Are you sure you paste this token correctly to the Postman? `console.log(access_token)` in the middleware to check

Comment: yes i pasted correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248919/discussion-between-sumanth-and-suleymansah).

Comment: The token you use is already expired, can you generate a new token and try?

Answer (score 1):

The token is in the form `Bearer <token>` so you need to split it before `verify`ing it:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
const access_token = req.headers["Authorization"];

 if (!access_token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied! no token provided.");

 const splitToken = access_token.split(' ');
 if (splitToken.length !== 2) return res.status(401).send("Access denied! invalid token.");

 const token = splitToken[1];

 try {
   const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "SECRET_JWT_CODE");
   req.receive = decoded;
   next();
 } catch (error) {
   res.status(400).send("invalid token.");
 }
};

module.exports = authenticate;
```

Also, make sure that you pass the token via the `Authorization` tab in Postman.
It should be available in `req.headers["Authorization"]` (capitalized) in the expected `Bearer <token>` format.

[image]

Comment: but it says `Access denied! invalid token.`

Comment: @sumanth Can you show the result of `console.log(req.headers)`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rDSj.png - here it is

Comment: @sumanth Try to change the way you send the parameter (see edited answer) [of course use your URL]

Comment: when I try the changes you have done it says `Access denied! no token provided.`

Comment: but i have provided the token

Comment: my token looks like this, is this is a right token `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzNTAzOTI0MTE3MmJlOWQxZTljYWY3YiIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY2MjAzOTExfQ.nNcxzrNZI_xNQTOm-EmHvgl5eTJn5xq5G2woLQQfjd4`

Comment: @sumanth According to https://jwt.io/ validator this is not a valid token. Anyway if the request returns `Access denied! no token provided.` it means that you are not reaching the `jwt.verify` call anyway. So the problem is still in the way you are passing the token to the function.